# Which is the best comparison method to analyze these data-sets?

Tags: data-visualization, descriptive-statistics

I need help on the best approach to perform statistical analysis to find out if there are any discrepancies in these data-sets for my students (for five independent years - with each year representing a different cohort of students):

1. I would like to compare their projects grades and final grades for each year
2. I would like to compare their predicted grades and final grades for each year

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have *repeated measures* data (also called *longitudinal* data) with two measurements per individual. I would start out with visualization, see for instance [Plotting and presenting longitudinal data, options?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/55018/plotting-and-presenting-longitudinal-data-options) and search this site. Maybe start with some kind of line plots, if you could post your data (in a readable form ..., if you cant share the data, some mock-up) we could experiment.

Also see [Best practice when analysing pre-post treatment-control designs](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3466/best-practice-when-analysing-pre-post-treatment-control-designs). For better advice you need to tell us more.